# Не получается отослать JSON

Tags: delphi, indy

Не получается отослать JSON используя компонент TIdHTTP:

```
        LJSONObject:= TJSONObject.Create;
        LJSONObject.AddPair(TJSONPair.Create('type','add_pop'));
        LJSONObject.AddPair(TJSONPair.Create('b',''+b+''));
        LJSONObject.AddPair(TJSONPair.Create('a',''+a+''));
        LJSONObject.AddPair(TJSONPair.Create('c',''+c+''));

        jsonText:=LJSONObject.ToString;
        MemoInfo.Lines.Add('From: ' + jsonText);

        post:= TStringList.Create;
        IdHTTP1.HandleRedirects:= True;

        try
          post.Add(jsonText);
          result:= IdHTTP1.Post('http://sfsf.fdgsg.fg/json/server.php', post);
          MemoInfo.Lines.Add(result);
        except
          post.Free;
        end;
```

В содержание json выводит From: `{"type":"add_pop","b":"1","a":"1","c":"6"}`

Ответ сервера `{"error":{"id":3,"text":"no param type, no param b, no param a, no param c"}}`

```
      JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();

            jsonObject.put("type", "add_pop");
            jsonObject.put("b", b);
            jsonObject.put("a", a);
            jsonObject.put("c", c);


            StringWriter out = new StringWriter();
            jsonObject.writeJSONString(out);

            String jsonText = out.toString();
            System.out.println(jsonText);
            String jsonBody = out.toString() ;

            DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost http = new HttpPost("http://sfsf.fdgsg.fg/json/server.php");
            StringEntity entity = new StringEntity(jsonBody, ContentType.APPLICATION_JSON);
            http.setEntity(entity);
            String response = httpclient.execute(http, new BasicResponseHandler());
            System.out.println(response);
```

Comment: в ответе сервера говорится, что вы присылаете не то, что он, видимо, ожидает. Приведите свои данные к нужному формату. _зы: `except post.free;` замените на `finally post.free`

Comment: А в php имеет значение если в данных JSON вместо Integer приходит число типа String ?

Comment: не имеет. Добавьте к вопросу код или API стороны сервера. вы уверены, что сервер вообще требует json на вход? что-то мне кажется, что он просто ждет обычные $_POST параметры `type, a,b,c`

Comment: @teran доступа к API нет отправлял на данный сервер json но только на java всё приходило единственное отличие было в том "c":6 была integer сейчас String. Что значит данные к нужному формату привести ?

Comment: дак попробуйте int проблемы вроде в этом нет никакой

Comment: @ teran пробовал всё так же

Comment: Возможно, проблема в том, что вы просто пишите параметры в `POST`, и никак не называете переменную параметра? У вас на стороне сервера пхп берет данные откуда то из `$_POST['data']`  потом делает `json_decode` для него. А вы же тут просто пишите `post.add(jsonText)`, хотя следует сделать что-то вида `post.values['data'] = jsonText;`. хотя мб и нет.

Comment: @teran я добавил для сравнения код на java

Comment: Единственное различие, которое я вижу, это заголовок `Content-type`.  Так что попробуйте сделать `idHttp1.Request.ContentType := 'application/json'`, и, возможно, вдобавок `idHttp1..Request.CharSet := 'utf-8'` если потребуется. В противном случае, я хз.

Comment: @teran Да всё верно поставьте в ответ. Надо было ещё дописать заголовок.

Comment: ответ добавил..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Согласно выясненным в комментариях нюансам, а также добавленного аналогичного работающего кода на `java`, проблема заключается в том, что сервер не может корректно распознать запрос, т.к. обрабатывает его, по всей видимости, на основании входящего типа контента.
Для решения проблемы необходимо явным образом указать заголовок `content-type` запроса равным `application/json`.

```
idHttp1.Request.ContentType := 'application/json';
```

---

*также вдобавок отмечу, что последняя секция кода должна выглядеть примерно так:*

```
post.Add(jsonText);
try 
    result:= IdHTTP1.Post('http://sfsf.fdgsg.fg/json/server.php', post);
    MemoInfo.Lines.Add(result);        
except on e : Exception
    memoInfo.text = 'Ошибка выполнения запроса: ' + e.message;
end;

post.Free();
```

*где исключительная ситуация при выполнении запроса обрабатывается с выводом соответствующего сообщения, после чего программа продолжает выполнение, очищая при этом ресурсы. Либо*

```
post.Add(jsonText);
try 
    result:= IdHTTP1.Post('http://sfsf.fdgsg.fg/json/server.php', post);
    MemoInfo.Lines.Add(result);        
finally
    post.Free();
end;
```

*При этом исключение не обрабатывается и передается вверх по стеку, но освобождение ресурсов все равно проводится в блоке `finally`.

у вас же получается, что ресурс `post` очищается только в случае возникновения исключения, что, конечно, можно списать на опечатку.*